# External Content type linq error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, external-content-type, linq

I have a list with an externa content type.
I am tring to fetch the element by server side code, but i get this exception:

> > Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure.BdcException

This is my code:

```
SPList myList = Web.Lists["listaName"];
SPListItem item = (from SPListItem item in myList.Items
                      where Convert.ToString(item["BdcIdentity"]) == myID
                      select item).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solded wrapping my code into `Using`s (probably the `Context` was missing)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(Web.Site.ID))
{
    var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    using (var scope = new SPServiceContextScope(context))
    {
        using (Web)
        {
            //my code
        }
    }
}
```